# Cordova Inappbrowser plugin display page on load

Tags: cordova, iframe, inappbrowser

This is my first time writing a mobile app using cordova. When the user navigates to my page, I want it to automatically display an external webpage. My first thought was to use an iframe, however I quickly realized that this is not a good way to do it, even if I whitelisted the site that I want. In searching I discovered the inappbrowser plugin.

The way it is typically used is as a link. For example:

```
<a href="{{url}}" onclick="window.open({{url}}, '_blank')">Link</a>
```

However I don't want the user to have to click anything for the inappbrowser to display the page. I simply want it to appear once the page has loaded. Could anyone suggest a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');

 window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
```

Documentation: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/index.html

Comment: Hi @Joerg. I tried that at first but without any success. It simply shows up as a blank page. I double checked and the InAppBrowser plugin is installed correctly. Am I missing something?

Comment: Does the inAppBrowser open? Open means, that a new window is coming up and you see on the bottom left the button «Done». Otherwise you have an error in your code. Are you waiting for cordova device ready? And by the way: What does the console is showing?

Comment: No, it does not open at all.